# Least Squares Optimization Converging on wrong solution

Tags: least-squares

I'm trying to calculate the position of a multi-constellation GNSS receiver using GPS and GLONASS satellites using least-squares optimization. Sparing the details, I have 5 equations to solve for 5 unknowns: (x, y, z, r_gps, r_gal).

4 equations are for GPS satellites, taking the form:

`sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2 + (z - z1)**2) - (pr - r_gps) = 0`

And 1 equation is for the sole GLONASS satellite, taking the form:

`sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2 + (z - z1)**2) - (pr - r_gal) = 0`

When implemented in python, the LS method converge to the same x,y,z solution no matter whether all 5 equations are taken, or only the 4 GPS equations or used. I.e, the 1 equation having the term `r_gal` is ignored. Mathematically, why is this the case?

Comment: To those interested the actual code can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420066/multi-constellation-gnss-trilateration-code-error)

Comment: Isn't it simply because the last equation can be rewritten as `sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2 + (z - z1)**2) - pr = -r_gal`? The LS method will just find the solutions for the other four variables, then use the values of `x`, `y`, and `z` to compute `r_gal`?

Comment: That’s a good point. I realise with another GLONASS equation the x,y,z solution will not longer face this problem. Thanks for your help, should have noticed this earlier